# Email Sending Trigger

Tags: email

I have set the Email Body in trigger as:

```
mail.setPlainTextBody('Please find the attachment of Order Confirmation and Terms and Conditions documents for the Order -'+ Orderid);

mail.setPlainTextBody('The name of The sales Agent' +userinfo.getusername());

mail.setPlainTextBody('The telephone number of the Sales Agent'+user.Phone);
```

**My output should be in the email body as:**

Please find the attachment of Order Confirmation and Terms and Conditions documents for the Order - 000000000

The name of The sales Agent:XXXXX

The telephone number of the Sales Agent:12345

**How i will write the code for above output to set as email body and how i will access the phone field of User,how i will set space and New line in Email body,please anyone regenerate the email body as per my output,guide me answer
how to access the phone field of user object**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A line break can be inserted with `\n`.
As far as I know, the only possibility to access a Users' phone number is with a SOQL query:

```
User currentUser = [Select Id, Phone from User where Id =:System.UserInfo.getUserId()];
System.debug(currentUser.Phone);`
```

You can send the email body you requested with

```
mail.setPlainTextBody('The name of The sales Agent' +userinfo.getusername() + '\n' + 'The telephone number of the Sales Agent:'+ currentUser.Phone);
```

You should have a look at [string concatenation](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Apex_Code:_The_Basics#Expression_Composition_and_Operators).

Comment: how i will set the these three inputs in same email body @fynh

Comment: please share the email body for my output @fynh

Comment: `mail.setPlainTextBody('The name of The sales Agent' +userinfo.getusername() + '\n' + 'The telephone number of the Sales Agent:'+ currentUser.Phone);` Should work.

You should have a look at [string concatenation](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Apex_Code:_The_Basics#Expression_Composition_and_Operators).

Comment: You should [edit] your answer with that info...